# How to turn flat list into a nested array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, tree

I have flat data:

```
$flatLists = [
    [
        'task',
        'updater',
        'updater_xml',
        'some_customer',
        'some_customer_de',

    ],
    [
        'task',
        'updater',
        'updater_xml',
        'some_customer',
        'some_customer_fr',
    ],
    [
        'task',
        'updater',
        'updater_json',
        'yet_another_customer',
        'yet_another_customer_us',
    ],
    [
        'task',
        'updater',
        'updater_json',
        'updater_flatfile',
    ],
];
```

It represents a heritage structure, the first element is the first parent, and each entry is a child.

I now want transform this flat array in a nested array, so that the result looks like:

```
$expectedArray = [
    'task' => [
        'updater' => [
            'updater_xml'  => [
                'some_customer' => [
                    'some_customer_de',
                    'some_customer_fr',
                ],
            ],
            'updater_json' => [
                'yet_another_customer' => [
                    'yet_another_customer_us',
                ],
                'updater_flatfile',
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

I have tried iterating over the flat list in multiple ways via `foreach`, `for` and nothing was close to working and my brain hurts now.

I don't expect a working code example, yet I would appreciate some hints in how to solve this issue and hopefully I can post an answer of my own. Right now, I am stuck.

Comment: Will you always have 4/5 elements per entry in the flat list? Or can it be any number of elements?

Comment: @MariM Amount of entries could be endless in theory.

Comment: Are leaves suposed to be values and not keys?

Comment: @Marek I really don't mind how they are stored. The last key could be both either a value or a key, in the end I do mind that the tree structure is maintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike your `$expectedArray`, this creates structure where leaves are keys with empty array as value:

```
$result = [];
foreach($flatLists as $list) {
  $target = &$result;
  foreach($list as $element) {
    if(!isset($target[$element])) {
      $target[$element] = [];
    }
    $target = &$target[$element];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this example, although I see you've already got a clener solution from @Marek.

```
function recurse( &$out, $index, $values ) {
    if ( isset( $values[ $index + 1 ] ) ) {
        $out[ $values[ $index ] ] = array();
        recurse( $out[ $values[ $index ] ], $index + 1, $values );
    } else {
        $out[] = $values[ $index ];
    }
}

$out = array_map( function( $item ) {
    recurse( $temp, 0, $item );
    return $temp;
}, $flatLists );


$result = call_user_func_array( 'array_merge_recursive', $out );
```